# 12V voltage drop over long wire

Tags: voltage

I have a cabin which is running off grid, using a solar panel and a (2*120 Ah 12V) battery.

I now want power in another building 20 meters away. One solution is to use an expensive high gauge (7 mm2)cable, to reduce the voltage drop - but that cable is also much more difficult to hide. I can't bury it without tripling the length.

I will have a bigger battery bank in the other building eventually, but the solar panels will remain on the main building.

When the voltage drops in the cable, is that also wasted Watt-hours? A few lamps will happily run on fewer volts. I am more worried about losing Wh's.

What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: Voltage drop will be proportional to current. What's the current?

Comment: Do you also want the battery in the second building to be able to send power back to the first building?

Comment: There are commercial buck-boost converters for this very purpose. Simplest solution I can think of is 12->110/230 Vac converter, normal mains cable installation in between, 12 V batter charger and a battery and you are good to go.

Comment: @winny I assume that this will introduce a huge loss in efficiency.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ideally, I would like to have all batteries in building 2, but I assume less current will go through the line with batteries in both ends.

Comment: Depends on how much power you want to transfer. If you step up the voltage ten times, you will have 1/10 of the transmission losses. There are very efficient batter chargers available and my good old rebranded BA power sine inverter does not get hot under load so I estimate 80+%. Do you need it running constantly or can you turn it off when not in use?

Comment: A better evaluation can be provided if we know how much power (/current) you will consume in the remote building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The voltage drop is caused by the **current**. At 12 V you need a lot of current to transport any amount of power. P = V * I so for 120 Watt at 12 V the current will be 10 A. If the cables have a total resistance of 0.1 ohm (which is quite low for 20m) the cables will drop 10 A * 0.1 ohm = 1 Volt. So you lose 1 V * 10 A = 10 Watt in the cables.

A solution is to **increase the voltage**. Let's do that again but now use 120 V instead of 12 V:

120 Watt at 120 V gives 1 A, 1 A * 0.1 ohm = 0.1 V drop, 0.1 V drop * 1 A = 0.1 W lost ! So that's 10 / 0.1 = 100 times more efficient !

How to increase the voltage ? You could use step-up (boost converter) to increase the voltage and step-down (buck converter) to efficiently lower the voltage again to 12 V. On Ebay many of these modules are sold. It depends on the amount of current you need at 12 V which type will suit your needs.

Comment: I am mostly curious of whether or not I am wasting *energy*. That is, will a light bulb in house 2 consume more watts per hour out of my batteries, than the same bulb in house 1? I assume it will be dimmer in house 2, but I am also hoping that it will consume fewer watts.

Comment: Power is energy per second. So yes, you lose energy. The long cable will heat up a few degrees (nothing to worry about). The light in the remote house will burn less bright. The **whole setup** will consume less power in total (due to the cable resistance, less current flows) **But** you will also get less light in the remote cabin. It will consume fewer watts but you get less light per watt and that is wastefull. The simplest solution would be to use LED lighting in the cabins as these are much more efficient than bulbs. So you need less current and waste less power.

Comment: If using an up converter to go from 12V to the higher 120V as shown in your example it is really necessary to also consider the efficiency of the up converter. It may indeed be more efficient by 100 times just considering the wiring BUT an up converter is not ideal and even the best ones may not achieve 90% efficiency. So it becomes a tradeoff balance to determine if 12V distribution loss is greater or less than up converter distribution scheme taking converter efficiency into account.

Comment: For your scenario, you have about 91.7% efficiency when transporting power at 12 V. Boosting at one end and bucking at the other even if both converters are 95% efficient will have an overall efficiency of 90.2% as a fairly optimistic best case. So the converter option doesn't sound like a likely win. Of course the real answer depends on how much power is actually needed, and the actual efficiency of the available converters. OP needs to do some actual engineering rather than just guess what solution is most efficient.

Comment: I think I have decided to have a battery in both houses. The "thinner" cable will be used to charge the battery in house B. The current should be fairly low, which means the resistance will be fairly low. If we use power in house B over the weekend, the system will use the weekdays to rebalance and I don't mind some wasted watts in that period. I am assuming that the voltage of both batteries eventually will be the same, and that battery B will not stabilize lower than battery A due to voltage drop.

Comment: *The current should be fairly low, which means the resistance will be fairly low* No, the **resistance** stays the same (it is a property of the wire) but the **voltage drop** and **energy loss** will be less.

Comment: @frodeborli  Given that, you're concerned about the energy budget I'm assuming you're using LED lamps,  12V LED lamps do not have a consistent response to reduced voltage,  it depends on how the lamp is designed.  if the lamp uses resistors to regulate the current it will be dimmer and use less energy, if it uses  a switching reulator it may be the same brightness or dimmer depending on how it was designed.